# Process multiples CSV files separately

Tags: powershell

I am trying to process multiples CSV files, editing one by one, and export each file in other directory with a new suffix in the file name. I don´t want to merge the files.

I tried too use the `Get-ChildItem` to list the files and loop each file individualy.

```
$ParentDir = Get-Location
$ProcDir = "$ParentDir" + "\Proc"
New-Item -Name "Proc" -ItemType "directory"
$csvs = Get-ChildItem -Path $ParentDir -Filter "*.csv"
foreach($csv in $csvs){
  $Name = $csvs.Name`
  $NewName = $csvs.BaseName+'_DeletedLinesColumns'+'.'+'csv'
  $file = Import-Csv -Path $ParentDir"$Name" -Delimiter ',' | where Ping -NotLike "`*`Header`*`" | select "Column1","Column3","Column7"
  $file | Export-Csv -Path $ProcDir"$NewName" -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: [1] What is `Ping` ?  [2] leave out the backticks in the string for `-notlike` [3] Please use [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) instead of concats like `$ParentDir"$Name"`, you'll miss the backslash between the path and the filename

Comment: It's merging them because you're outputting in a single loop to one location. Also `import-csv` is going to be a better cmdlet for you to use. You will also want to add a "\" after `$ProcDir` to separate the foldername from the filename. You could put into separate files if you use `$csvs.basename` as part of your output filename or differentiate the output file somehow.

Comment: I did the suggested modifications, but still not working. I created two simple files to test, named "File1.csv" and "File2.csv". The result was this file: "File1 File2 _DeletedLinesColumns . csv". A single file. If I am processing two CSVs I would like to also have two CSVs files as result. Any other suggestions (Please)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested your csv code, but this should get you on the right track

```
$ParentDir = $PSScriptRoot
$ProcDir = "$ParentDir\Proc"
if(!(test-path $ProcDir)){New-Item -Path $ParentDir -Name "Proc" -ItemType "directory"}
$csvs = Get-ChildItem -Path $ParentDir -Filter "*.csv"
foreach($csv in $csvs){
  $NewName = $csv.BaseName+'_DeletedLinesColumns.csv'
  Import-Csv -Path $csv.FullName -Delimiter ',' | ?{$_.Ping -NotLike "`*`Header`*`"} | select "Column1","Column3","Column7" | Export-Csv -Path "$ProcDir\$NewName" -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Comment: I did the suggested modifications, but still not working. I created two simple files to test, named "File1.csv" and "File2.csv". The result was this file: "File1 File2 _DeletedLinesColumns . csv". A single file. If I am processing two CSVs I would like to also have two CSVs files as result. Any other suggestions (Please)

Comment: Oops I didn't catch a mistake in your code - you should've had "$csv.BaseName" but you had "$csvs.BaseName" i.e not using the iteration variable. Have edited the answer

Comment: It works!!!!! Closing the question.